# CSS and HTML Navbar fluent/flush/against main header image

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver, navbar

Im having some trouble! Something really simple i believe. However its troubling me.

I am trying to achieve:

1) The navigation bar to be the width of the main image above it.

if anyone can solve this for me i would be truly greatful and it would be a huge help. Im very new to coding and this has been hard for me.

Ive done my fair share of looking for an answer but have failed so far.

here is a picture of the page http://i46.tinypic.com/w9a80i.jpg please excuse the white box covering the graphic that is simple for privacy etc

css:

```
/* Reset */

html, body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    }

a {
text-decoration: none;
}

ul, li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

img.floatLeft { 
    float: left; 
    margin: 4px; 
}
*
{
   margin:  0;
   padding: 0;
}

body {background-color:#F1F1F1; }

#outer { width: 900px; margin:auto;}

#wrapper { width: 900px; margin:0; background-color: #666; }

#list-nav { width: 700px; float: right;}

ul#list-nav li a {
 text-decoration:none;
 padding:5px 0;
 width: auto;
 background:#999;
 color:#eee;
 float: left;
}

ul#list-nav li a {
  text-align:center;
  border-left:1px solid #fff;
  width: 100px;
}

ul#list-nav li a:hover {
  background:#CCC;
  color:#ffff;
}

#content-fullwidth { width:100%; }
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head> 
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Caption' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>

<div id="outer">

<div id="wrapper">
  <a href="main.html"><img src="css/Images/banner top.jpg"  /></a>

<div id="navbar">

  <ul id="list-nav">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>  

</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: is it ok if you use javascript?

Comment: @user1743319 Possible to post the full HTML code? Or is there any live preview so that we can check? I tried to reproduce here: http://jsbin.com/azutex/1 but it seems to work well.

Comment: @user1743319 Are the remaining just `</body></html>`, without them it wouldn't work the same in all the browsers. Just to ensure. Check out the link in my previous comment. Do say what is to be changed.

Comment: ahh yes sorry i will try your changes now.. please bare with me ! thank you for your help

Comment: I just want the navigation bar to flush against the graphic thats above it. I also want it to be the same width...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understand well, but i think that's what you are looking for.
First, your nav was 700px large, also your image and container are 900px.

Make your `#list-nav : width:100%` as large as the container and the image

Then the li, which are 5 of them, must be 20% large of the ul(so they have the same width)

`#list-nav li{display:inline-block;width:20%;float:left}`

[Here's your code with modification](http://jsfiddle.net/audre7/Wfe9a/2/)

Is that what you wanted to do ?
You can also do it with a display:table-cell trick.

Comment: Thank you very much its almost spot on! Its just the navbar seems to be one pixel to right 

http://i46.tinypic.com/290sqa1.png

Comment: do you see what i mean its just aligned a little over to far.

Comment: @user1743319 you give #list-nav "width: 700px;", that's why the navbar is aligned a little over to far from right

Comment: it also has this problem now http://i46.tinypic.com/2afmqt3.png a small unidentified string of text shows up ?

Comment: @chanjarster  i have now edited to meet requirements 

`#wrapper { width: 900px; margin:0; background-color: #666; }

ul#list-nav li {
    display:inline-block;
}

#list-nav li{display:inline-block;width:20%;float:left}

ul#list-nav li a {
 text-decoration:none;
 padding:5px 0;
 width: auto;
 background:#999;
 color:#eee;
 float: left;
}`

Comment: and if you make `ul li:first-child{border-left:none}`, cause the first item of your menu don't need that border, and that's make your nav goes left a pixel. Is that right like this ?

Answer (score 0):

remove the width definition of #list-nav: `#list-nav{ /*width: 700px;*/ float: right;}`

and add this

```
ul#list-nav li {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: unfortunatly that didnt do anything ... please see the image below (excuse the blocked out graphic its for privacy etc)

http://i46.tinypic.com/2564fi1.png

As you can see the navbar has almost been done but not quite its still out of line slightly...

​

Comment: Also an odd string of text now shows i46.tinypic.com/2afmqt3.png

Comment: @user1743319 . Put your code on http://jsfiddle.net and make sure you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have done that it does reproduce the problem of the navbar now being aligned to right so it seems. ?

Comment: IT HAS NOW BEEN FIXED ! However im still troubled as to how to get rid of the string of text ? that follows it it seems like some type of error